# Delete Android's Built-In browser's History using AsyncTask

Tags: android, browser, android-asynctask

Hello I'm trying to develop an android app that can delete Browser History(Built In or Default), so far I was able to delete History properly, but when the mobile browser was having lot of History then Force To Close alert box comes, I know I'm doing all the stuff in UI thread, So I gone through AsyncTask article, but not able to understand properly where to put my history deleting code please help me, Thanks in advance.

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondClass.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my SecondClass code

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
ProgressDialog pd;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_class);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait", true,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }.execute((Void[])null);
}
}
```

Please Help me, Thanks in Advance

Here is my LogCat

```
W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity com.example.handlerlearn/.SecondClass

W/InputManagerService(   61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40720228

E/WindowManager( 2089): Activity com.example.handlerlearn.SecondClass has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40525230 that was originally added here

E/WindowManager( 2089): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.handlerlearn.SecondClass has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40525230 that was originally added here

E/WindowManager( 2089):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)

E/WindowManager( 2089):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)

E/WindowManager( 2089):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)

E/WindowManager( 2089):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
```

Comment: what is the problem with AsyncTask code?

Comment: How did you clean the History before introducing the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Just minor help: you can call execute() with no parameters and pleas encapsulate your variables (private).

Comment: @g00dy I was just invoking `Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());` in `btn.setOnClick`

Comment: So what's the problem to use it in the `AsyncTask`. If it gives you some problems, you can use it like that : `Browser.clearHistory(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());` when some event occur or just when the `AsyncTask` is started. Please try it and get back with the results.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar Please see the updated post, this is my Logcat

Comment: @g00dy Tried your approach, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Also one more thing change:

`pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait", true,false);`

to

`pd = ProgressDialog.create().show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait", true,false);`

This might be the missing dialog screen, it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: You removed the return in `doInBackground()` and put `.create()` as well and it still shows you the same error in the `LogCat`, even after Project->Clean?